# What is the best way to implement search and filter in a simple code?

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

Currently I am using [nicolaslopezj/searchable](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) for my laravel Search.

Search is good, but I want to add also a filter on it and my filter such as sex, class or location.

For example in this case:

1 --- Jane Doe --- F --- Class A --- USA

2 --- John Doe --- M --- Class B --- PH

my current code is something like this:

```
if (isset ($keyword) )
$voters = Voter::search($request->keyword)->paginate(10);

if (isset ($keyword) && isset($request->sex))
$voters = Voter::search($request->keyword)->where('sex', $request->sex)->paginate(10);

if ( !isset($keyword) && isset($request->sex))
$voters = Voter::where('sex', $request->sex)->paginate(10);

if( isset($keyword && !isset($request->sex)
$voters = Voter::search($request->keyword)->paginate(10);
```

So any idea how to minimize a lot of conditions? Is there a one-liner code/query for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Model::query()` and `Request::has()` method to check request.. for example..

```
$voters = Voter::query();

if ($request->has('keyword'))
    $voters = $voters->search($request->keyword);

if ($request->has('sex'))
    $voters = $voters->where('sex', $request->sex);

$voters = $voters->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I optimized your code:

```
$voters = Voter::on();

if (isset ($request->keyword))
    $voters = $voters->search($request->keyword);

if (isset($request->sex))
    $voters = $voters->where('sex', $request->sex);

$voters = $voters->paginate(10);
```